# ORA-00823: Specified value of sga_target greater than sga_max_size dba

Tags: oracle-12c

I was doing a modification in my database and something I should not have done well and I got the following error :

> ```
> SQL> startup
> ORA-00823: Specified value of sga_target greater than sga_max_size
> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
> ```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

- Open the **pfile** and set `sga_target=0` and save it.
- After :

  ```
  create spfile from pfile;
  create pfile from spfile;
  ```
- Now start the database :

  ```
  SQL> startup

  ORACLE instance started.
  Total System Global Area 5133828096 bytes
  Fixed Size                  8929496 bytes
  Variable Size             956305192 bytes
  Database Buffers         4160749568 bytes
  Redo Buffers                7843840 bytes
  Database mounted.
  Database opened.
  ```